# how to display DatePicker and other user inputs in one messagebox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Hello I have been trying to make it so that a user inputs various information (textboxes, comboboxes, datepicker) and clicks a button, all of the input information is displayed within one Messagebox. Also, I am trying to create Validation, where each field must contain some sort of input/character other than being empty before the messagebox displaying all of the inputs appears.

```
    Dim s, sOut As String
    Dim x As System.Xml.XmlElement = cbEval.SelectedItem

    If x Is Nothing _
            OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTotal.Text) _
            OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(cbEval.SelectedItem) _
            OrElse DatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in any empty fields.")
    Else
        sOut = String.Format("Evaluator Name: {0}" & Environment.NewLine() & _
               "Text: {1}" & Environment.NewLine() & _
               "CbValue: {2}" & Environment.NewLine() & _
               "Date3: {3}", _
               x.InnerText, txtTotal.Text, cbEval.SelectedItem, DatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString())
        MessageBox.Show(sOut)
    End If
```

I have run into errors concerning the datepicker: "Is operator not accepting operand type of Date" and "Is not accepting type of Boolean" for a combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
'-----------------------------Check if all Fields are occupied-------------------------
if TextBox1.Text <> "" And TextBox2.Text <> "" And ComboBox1.Text <> "" Then
Dim Information As String = ""

Information = "Your Name is: " & TextBox1.Text & " And Your Living in: " &  TextBox2.Text & " Your Favorite Animal is: " & ComboBox1.text & " The Date and Time is Now: " & DateTimePicker1.Value
MessageBox(Information)
Else
MessageBox("Please Fill Out all the Information")

End If
End Sub
```

Try This...

Comment: Awesome! I'm a lot closer to getting this to work, however the DatePicker1.Value does not work :/  It says: 'Value' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker'.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I got it! Had to use DatePicker1.SelectedDate

```
If txtTotal.Text <> "" And txtComments.Text <> "" And cbEval.Text <> "" Then
        Dim Information As String = ""

        Information = "Your Name is: " & txtTotal.Text & " And Your Living in: " & txtComments.Text & " Your Favorite Animal is: " & cbEval.Text & " The Date and Time is Now: " & DatePicker1.SelectedDate
        MessageBox.Show(Information)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please Fill Out all the Information")

    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you so much!